# How to find output in CONFUSING Beginner Java Problem

Tags: java, arrays

I'm fairly new to Java. Can someone please explain why this would have an output of 18? I tried doing this out by hand and it continues to give me 12. I thought that when declaring a new array equal to another, they are independent from each other and don't affect the other. Any help would be appreciated!

```
public class NumberProblem{

     public static void main(String []args){
        int[] k = {2,3,5,7,9,11,-4};
        int[] m = k;
        m[1] = 4;
        m[2] = m[5];
        System.out.println(k[2] + m[3]);

     }
}
```

Comment: Nope. `m` and `k` are referencing the same array. Java does not implicitly copy arrays.

Comment: Where is new keyword?

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: `m` = `k` does not copy `k` to  `m`. instead both point to the same "target" = array

Comment: Can help - see `11+7=18` and you can see it too with `System.out.printf("%d+%d=%d%n", k[2], m[3], k[2]+m[3]);` or you can use this wonderful "new" invention called a [debugger](https://www.computerhistory.org/tdih/september/9/) --- and by new I mean so old Thomas Edison coined the term (or knew of it). Perhaps worth mentioning that Grace Murray Hopper invented the compiler (and led the committee that developed [COBOL](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/04/20/brush-up-your-cobol-why-is-a-60-year-old-language-suddenly-in-demand/?cb=1), and you can tell COBOL was developed by a committee).

Comment: So if there was "new" keyword when declaring the array, then it would be independent?

Comment: @TimothyWong Not really. You **could** copy the array using `new` and then a loop, but it's much easier to use `int[] m = Arrays.copyOf(k, k.length);`